# Convert iTunes COM object to byte array / Use iTunesApp object on multiple processes

Tags: c#, com, itunes, itunes-app

On my computer multiple programs are running that need to access the iTunesApp interface provided by the COM object. After some testing I discovered that certain interaction (specifically event listening) are only possible in the "original" instance of the object. That means if iTunes is already running and I run `iTunesApp app = new iTunesApp()` I create a iTunesApp instance which can access the library and play/pause etc., but doesn't get called when events like `app.OnPlayerPlayEvent` are fired. If I want event listening I have to run `iTunesApp app = new iTunesApp()` with iTunes not already running.

So my solution to this was that I just have a program run at boot, start iTunes and share the `iTunesApp` object with any other program that needs it. Unfortunately, the class isn't serializible so I cannot convert it easily to a byte[] array.

My question would be: Is there any possibility to convert the object to a byte array and share it via `MemoryMappedFile`, `Socket` or similar? I've tried `BinaryFormatter.Serialize()` as well as the `ProtoBuf` package, but neither worked. Or is there a method or something that allows me to get the `iTunesApp` object from a running instance of iTunes?

Comment: Google for GetRunningObjectTable() and examples.  I don't know if iTunes creates an entry in the ROT, but it's worth looking at the ROT to see if it does.

Answer (score 1):

COM has a standard way of marshaling objects. Call [CoMarshalInterface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678428.aspx) to marshal the object into a stream (for the C# declaration, see [CoMarshalInterface on pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ole32.comarshalinterface)). You can then read the bytes that were written into the IStream, give those bytes to any process, unmarshal using [CoUnmarshalInterface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693382.aspx). Make sure you use the correct flags for your use case.